# Function returning - PHP

Tags: php, function, return

This is just a curiosity question that I didn't know how to search via google.

Some functions are like this:

```
function foo()
{
    $bar = 'Hello World';

    return;
}
```

What is `retun;` going to return? This is kinda ridiculous.

Comment: @Breezer no, it returns `null` instead.

Comment: Could `var_dump(foo())` answer to your question ?

Comment: as stated here: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php it just returns NULL

Comment: Why is it ridiculous? If the very last statement in a function is a blank `return;`, yes, that's pretty unnecessary. But simple blank `return` statements are useful to conditionally exit a function if you don't need to return any particular value.

Comment: return keyword is used for return some value from that function if you simply not return any value from function than obviously it returns null value.

Comment: Yeah, it does sound ridiculous if you think about it. The word "return" can used for transitively and intransitively. In programming,  it's always the transitive meaning of the word that's employed. A function returns something back to the caller. When the keyword just sit by itself (because nothing is returned) then it looks like the intransitive form is used when it actually isn't.

Comment: A question like this should be answered with a link to the PHP manual, with a RTFM tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does return `null`. If `return` is called without any variable or value `return` will return `null`.

A note from PHP manual page

> If no parameter is supplied, then the parentheses must be omitted and
>   NULL will be returned. Calling return() with parentheses but with no
>   arguments will result in a parse error.

Answer (score 5):

> **Note:** If no parameter is supplied, then the parentheses must be omitted and `NULL` will be returned. Calling `return` with parentheses but with no arguments will result in a parse error.
>
> http://www.php.net/return

Answer (score 0):

`return` will simply return control to who called that function, returning a `NULL` value. So, if you have this snippet of code

```
function bar()
{
  echo 'bar';
  $a = foo();
  echo 'foobar';
}
```

First it prints `'bar'` string, then control is passed to `foo()` function who assign to (local) `$bar` variable `'Hello World'` string value. Then this variable is destroyed (you exit from function) and control returns to `bar()` function. After that a `'foobar'` string is displayed.
Note that `a` will have a `NULL` value

Answer (score 0):

if you are using

```
function foo()
{
    $bar = 'Hello World';

    return;
}
echo $temp=foo();
```

than it return **NULL value**

and if you are using

```
function foo()
{
    $bar = 'Hello World';

    return $bar;
}

    echo $temp=foo();
```

than it returns Hello World.

Answer (score 0):

You could have figured that out very easy:

```
function foo()
{
    $bar = 'Hello World';

    return;
}

var_dump( foo() );
```